# What is the base form for 되세요?

Tags: vocabulary, translation, meaning

What is the base form for 되세요

Example Hello Formal:

```
이름이 어떻게 되세요 ?
```

Answer (score 1):

It is 되시다, which is an honorific form of 되다 (to become, to work out).

> 되시(다) + 어요 => 되시어요 => 되셔요 => 되세요.

시어 contracting to 셔 is a case of the common 이어->여 pattern, whereas 셔요 becoming 세요 only happens in this type of 시어요/셔요 case. The latter only happens when 시어요/셔요 comes after the verb stem, not in general, purely for phonetic reasons (세요 is easier to pronounce and sounds more natural than 셔요).  되시어요 and 되셔요 are also valid forms even though they are not as commonly used as 되세요.

Other examples:

- 가시어요 / 가셔요 / 가세요 (가시다).
- 잡수시어요 / 잡수셔요 / 잡수세요 (잡수시다).
- 좋으시어요 / 좋으셔요 / 좋으세요 (좋으시다).